# WordPress AJAX - store jquery variable and echo it in php - function.php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Is it possible to send jQuery variable to function.php, and use it in some php function? Via AJAX or probably.

Theme related, not using a plugin.

Eg.
I have some post CSS classes added on 'client side' via jQuery on click.

Can I use this classes on 'server side' so I can pass them in any page of my theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WordPress environment**

First of all, in order to achieve this task, it's recommended to register then enqueue a jQuery script that will push the request to the server. These operations will be hooked in `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook. In the same hook you should put `wp_localize_script` that it's used to include arbitrary Javascript. By this way there will be a JS object available in front end. This object carries on the correct url to be used by the jQuery handle.

Please take a look to:

1. [wp_register_script();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) function
2. [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook
3. [wp_enqueue_script();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function
4. [wp_localize_script();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function

**File: functions.php 1/2**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so18550905_enqueue_scripts' );
function so18550905_enqueue_scripts(){
  wp_register_script( 'ajaxHandle', get_template_directory() . 'PATH TO YOUR SCRIPT FILE', array(), false, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle' );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin_ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

**File: jquery.ajax.js**

This file makes the ajax call.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
  //Some event will trigger the ajax call, you can push whatever data to the server, simply passing it to the "data" object in ajax call
  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, // this is the object instantiated in wp_localize_script function
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
      action: 'myaction', // this is the function in your functions.php that will be triggered
      name: 'John',
      age: '38'
    },
    success: function( data ){
      //Do something with the result from server
      console.log( data );
    }
  });
});
```

**File: functions.php 2/2**

Finally on your functions.php file there should be the function triggered by your ajax call.
Remember the suffixes:

1. wp_ajax ( allow the function only for registered users or admin panel operations )
2. wp_ajax_nopriv ( allow the function for no privilege users )

These suffixes plus the action compose the name of your action:

`wp_ajax_myaction` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'so18550905_wp_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'so18550905_wp_ajax_function' );
function so18550905_wp_ajax_function(){
  //DO whatever you want with data posted
  //To send back a response you have to echo the result!
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo $_POST['age'];
  wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
}
```

Hope it helps!

Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use AJAX to send your jQuery variable. (or any Javascript Variable)

Simply do a JSON.stringify(any-Variable-Here) then you get a corresponding string.

Send the value via AJAX to any php file like:

```
var toBeSent = JSON.stringify($($('#selector')[0]).attr('class'));
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'function.php',
  data: toBeSent,
  success: function(data){ // any action to be performed after function.php returns a value.
  },
  dataType: 'text'
});
```

NOTE: I've stringified the items here so that you can access the variables on the server side by doing simple splits.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can

```
$('element').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);

    //do stuff on click

    //send this elements class to the server    
    $.ajax({
       url: "some.php",
       data: {
           class: el.attr('class')
       },
       success: function(r){
           alert("class name sent successfully to some.php");
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

another option for you could be [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$('#myDiv').click(function(){
var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
var url = 'page.php';
   $.post(url, { class: myClass })
   .done( function() {
     alert('class sent to ' + url);
   });
 }); 

});
```